# Finding matching PDF files in different folders and merging the two files into one

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have code which currently loops through one folder, finds two matching pdf-filenames and merges them into 1 pdf-file always in the same order. File 1 then File 2. My code is slow, maybe because merging PDF files takes a long time, but also because it has to search one folder and match filenames. Before I searched through two folders, but that took too long. I do not want to write the filenames to an Excel-file and then match, but I want to merge the PDF files immediately when VBA finds a match. I found some code and adjusted it to my needs and put some new things into it.

I have seen a lot of code using Acrobat or Pdftk, but I do not have Acrobat and Pdftk does not work with me even though I do exactly what is written on several sites. For some reason Pdftk does not merge my files.

My code matches filenames based on the first part of the filename, before the AnotherWord 2014.pdf or before SomeWord.pdf.

- Example document name1: John Doe SomeWord.pdf
- Example document name2: John Doe AnotherWord 2014.pdf

Please look at this code and please post code which will do the same thing, only much faster. My code isn't the best, but it works. I use PDF reDirect Pro v2.5.2 (freeware) and a reference to the program.

```
    Sub MergePDF_Files()
'Only works with PDF reDirect Pro v2.5.2
'And needs to have a reference to PDF_reDirect_v2500 and PDF reDirect Pro Remote Control
Dim fs As Object
Dim fld As Object
Dim fld2 As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim objFile2 As Object
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oPDF As New PDF_reDirect_v25002.Batch_RC_AXD
Dim TempBool As Boolean
Dim Files_to_Merge(1) As String
Dim ObjFileName() As String
Dim CellNameValue() As String
Dim ofn As String
Dim cnv As String
Dim i As Integer

Set fld = fs.GetFolder("C:\MyFolder\PDF Merge\Merging Area")
Set fld2 = fs.GetFolder("C:\MyFolder\PDF Merge\Merging Area\Merged")
i = 1

For Each objFile In fld.files
For Each objFile2 In fld.files
    CellNameValue() = Split(objFile.Name, " SomeWord.pdf")
    cnv = CellNameValue(0)
    ObjFileName() = Split(objFile2.Name, " AnotherWord 2014.pdf")
    ofn = ObjFileName(0)
    Files_to_Merge(1) = fld & "\" & ofn & " AnotherWord 2014.pdf"
    Files_to_Merge(0) = fld & "\" & cnv & " SomeWord.pdf"
    If StrComp(ofn, cnv) = 0 Then
    With oPDF

        TempBool = .Utility_Merge_PDF_Files(fld2 & "\" & ofn & " AnotherWord 2014.pdf", Files_to_Merge) 'The file merges here unless it generates an error and goes to If Not TempBool Then...

        If Not TempBool Then
            'MsgBox "An Error Occured: etc.
        Else
            'Optional
        End If
    End With
    End If
    i = i + 1
    Next objFile2
     i = i + 1
    Next objFile
    Set oPDF = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I would use [Dictionary Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx) to store all filenames of Folder1 then for each File in Folder2, check for Exists. If exists then merge them.

Comment: @PatricK 
Hello Patrick, thank you for the suggestion. Could you please show how this code would look like? I looked at your link, but I would not know how to compare them and after that merge them.

Comment: After reviewing your code carefully, Dictionary will not help. Instead I will use the [.NET System.Collections.ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) will post code soon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot do full test as I do not have that PDF software of yours. But the idea is that process all file names in that folder 1, store them in a collection, also if the file name ends with " SomeWord.pdf" then add to another collection.

When done, process the other collection and see if a matched " AnotherWord 2014.pdf" found in first collection. Merge if found.

Reworked after Trial is downloaded.

```
Option Explicit

Private oFullList As Object, oMyList As Object, oFSO As Object

Private Const FDR1 = "C:\Test\"
Private Const FDR2 = "C:\Test\Merged\"

Private Const sAppend1 = " SomeWord.pdf"
Private Const sAppend2 = " AnotherWord 2014.pdf"

Private oPDF As New PDF_reDirect_v25002.Batch_RC_AXD
Private lFiles As Long

Sub Main()
    lFiles = 0
    Debug.Print Now & vbTab & "Program Started"
    '===[ Create Collection Objects ]===
    ' FullList stores all the filenames in the directory
    If oFullList Is Nothing Then
        Set oFullList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") ' Create if not created
    Else
        oFullList.Clear ' Remove all old entries
    End If
    ' MyList only stores filenames that will be checked for merge
    If oMyList Is Nothing Then
        Set oMyList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") ' Create if not created
    Else
        oMyList.Clear
    End If
    '===[ Check FileSystemObject ]===
    If oFSO Is Nothing Then
        Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    End If
    '===[ Main procedures ]===
    CheckFiles
    'ListFiles ' Skipped, debug only
    ProcessMergeFiles
    '===[ Clean Up ]===
    Set oFullList = Nothing
    Set oMyList = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
    Set oPDF = Nothing
    '===[ Print Summary ]===
    Debug.Print Now & vbTab & "Program Finished. " & lFiles & " merged PDFs has been created"
End Sub

Private Sub CheckFiles()
    Dim oFDR As Object, oFile As Object, sTmp As String, n As Long
    '===[ Process all filenames of FDR1 ]===
    For Each oFile In oFSO.GetFolder(FDR1).Files
        sTmp = oFile.Name
        ' Add to FullList collection
        oFullList.Add sTmp
        ' Only add to MyList collection if it ends with sAppend1
        n = InStr(1, sTmp, sAppend1, vbTextCompare)
        If n > 0 Then
            oMyList.Add Left(sTmp, n - 1) ' Stores only the prefix
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ListFiles()
    Dim i As Long
    Debug.Print "=== Listing " & oMyList.Count & " item(s) in oMyList ==="
    For i = 0 To oMyList.Count - 1
        Debug.Print i + 1 & vbTab & oMyList(i)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessMergeFiles()
    Dim i As Long, sTmp As String
    For i = 0 To oMyList.Count - 1
        sTmp = oMyList(i)
        If oFullList.Contains(sTmp & sAppend2) Then
            'Debug.Print "Merge file pair found: """ & sTmp & """"
            MergeFiles sTmp
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub MergeFiles(sFilePrefix As String)
    Dim bSuccess As Boolean
    Dim aFiles() As String ' <- Required datatype

    If oPDF Is Nothing Then
        Set oPDF = New PDF_reDirect_v25002.Batch_RC_AXD
    End If

    ReDim aFiles(1)
    aFiles(0) = FDR1 & sFilePrefix & sAppend1
    aFiles(1) = FDR1 & sFilePrefix & sAppend2

    With oPDF
        bSuccess = .Utility_Merge_PDF_Files(FDR2 & "\" & sFilePrefix & sAppend2, aFiles)
        If bSuccess Then
            Debug.Print "Merged pdf files with prefix """ & sFilePrefix & """"
            lFiles = lFiles + 1
        Else
            Debug.Print "Failed to merge pdf files with prefix " & sFilePrefix
            Debug.Print "ERR(" & .LastErrorNumber & "):" & .LastErrorDescription
            .Reset_Errors
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Are you using .Net's `ArrayList` in this code? I didn't realize you could do that. Feel free to drop by the [VBA Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba) sometime.

Comment: @PatricK Thank you very much for the code. I am going to check it and let you know if it worrks or not, but the code looks very interesting. I already posted a reply yesterday, but for some reason it wasn't posted.
Regards,
Richard

Comment: @PatricK
Hi, I get a Run-timer error 13 Type Mismatch on this line:
<pre><code>bSuccess = .Utility_Merge_PDF_Files(FDR2 & "\" & sFilePrefix & sAppend2, aFiles)</code></pre>
bSuccess at that moment is False
Any idea why that could be? Sorry I do not understand how to put code in like it should, I do not understand the help explanation.
Richard

Comment: I don't have documentation on using the `.Utility_Merge_PDF_Files()`, what are the input types? I am guessing it doesn't like `aFiles`.

Comment: Try revised code, adopting what you used that works. What you get in the **Immediate** window?

Comment: Merge file pair found: 
This is the only thing is said in the Immediate window

Comment: Dim Files_to_Merge(1) As String
 TempBool = .Utility_Merge_PDF_Files(fld2 & "\" & ofn & " AnotherWord 2014.pdf", Files_to_Merge)

Comment: aFiles As Variant
aFiles = Array(sFilePrefix & sAppend1, sFilePrefix & sAppend2)

Comment: Mine was a string, yours is a Variant, an Array
Is it possible to adjust this somehow?

Comment: Putting in comments and code does not really go together, it is easier to make separate comments to not lose the overview

Comment: Revised again, changes in `Sub MergeFiles`. Can you test

Comment: With your adjusted code I get the following error message here ----    bSuccess = oPDF.Utility_Merge_PDF_Files(FDR2 & "\" & sFilePrefix & sAppend2, aFiles)
---- Compile Error:
Type mismatch: array or user-defined type expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20877/discussion-between-patrick-and-rhberendsen).

Comment: @PatricK  -  It works like a charm. Thank you for your perseverance!! This code is much faster than my previous. Thank you very much. I think it can be applied to all kind of other things too!!
Regards,
Richard

Answer (score 2):

First off, let me say that I ***really*** like that you've documented what references your code requires. Nothing is more frustrating than trying to figure that out on your own when one is missing. Kudos.

Now I'll repeat something I've said often.

> 1. Make it work.
> 2. Make it right.
> 3. Then, make it fast.

You've already made it work, we should make it right before trying to make it fast.

I recommend adding a reference to the Scripting library that you're using. You already have other references in your code. I don't see a reason not to early bind that one too. It gives you the advantage of intellisense and turns runtime errors (i.e. *typos*) into compile time errors.

The secondary benefit to doing this is it makes it easier to find `FileSystemObject`'s `FileExists` method. The inner loop is completely unnecessary. This should make it a bit faster as we've removed a nested loop, but I think you're correct in thinking that the PDf merge is taking up most of the time.

```
Dim targetFilePath As String
For Each objFile In fld.Files
    CellNameValue() = Split(objFile.Name, " SomeWord.pdf")
    targetFilePath = "C:\MyFolder\PDF Merge\Merging Area\" & CellNameValue(0) & " AnotherWord 2014.pdf"

    If fs.FileExists(targetFilePath) Then
        'merge here
    End If
```

The third benefit is some code clarity. You may or may not realize it, but you're relying on the fact that the `Folder` object's default property is it's path.

> ```
>     Files_to_Merge(1) = fld & "\" & ofn & " AnotherWord 2014.pdf"
>     Files_to_Merge(0) = fld & "\" & cnv & " SomeWord.pdf"
> ```

I don't like relying on default properties when I can avoid it. It's better to be explicit. This would be more properly written as:

```
    Files_to_Merge(1) = fld.Path & "\" & ofn & " AnotherWord 2014.pdf"
    Files_to_Merge(0) = fld.Path & "\" & cnv & " SomeWord.pdf"
```

You don't need to early bind to do this, but it certainly makes it easier to find the property.

There are a few things I don't care for in the next snippet.

> ```
>     With oPDF
>
>         TempBool = .Utility_Merge_PDF_Files(fld2 & "\" & ofn & " AnotherWord 2014.pdf", Files_to_Merge) 'The file merges here unless it generates an error and goes to If Not TempBool Then...
>
>         If Not TempBool Then
>             'MsgBox "An Error Occured: etc.
>         Else
>             'Optional
>         End If
>     End With
> ```

1. You're using a with block.... why? You've effectively added 2 lines of code and an additional 12 or so keystrokes. No reason to. Just make the call directly on `oPDF`.

   ```
   TempBool = oPDF.Utility_Merge_PDF_Files(fld2 & "\" & ofn & " AnotherWord 2014.pdf", Files_to_Merge)
   ```
2. You're doing nothing with the result stored in `TempBool`. Either do something with it or remove the variable and `If` block. (`TempBool` is a pretty bad name by the way, if it stays, consider renaming it `MergeResult`.)

This is what I came up with. I couldn't test it, but it should be pretty close to what you need and easier to understand. I went ahead and just renamed all the variables to something meaningful.

```
Sub MergePDF_Files()
'Only works with PDF reDirect Pro v2.5.2
'And needs to have a reference to PDF_reDirect_v2500 and PDF reDirect Pro Remote Control
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim sourceFolder As Folder
    Dim destinationFolder As Folder
    Dim sourceFile As File
    Dim oPDF As New PDF_reDirect_v25002.Batch_RC_AXD
    Dim Files_to_Merge(1) As String
    Dim CellNameValue() As String

    Set sourceFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\MyFolder\PDF Merge\Merging Area")
    Set destinationFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\MyFolder\PDF Merge\Merging Area\Merged")

    Dim targetFileName As String

    For Each sourceFile In fld.Files
        CellNameValue() = Split(objFile.Name, " SomeWord.pdf")
        targetFileName = CellNameValue(0) & " AnotherWord 2014.pdf"

        If fs.FileExists(fld.Path & targetFileName) Then
            Files_to_Merge(0) = sourceFile.Path
            Files_to_Merge(1) = targetFilePath

            oPDF.Utility_Merge_PDF_Files destinationFolder.Path & "\" & targetFileName
        End If

    Next 
    Set oPDF = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `Next sourceFile` instead of `Next objFile`

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about @PatricK. =;)-

Comment: Hello @RubberDuck
Thank you very much for the code. I am going to test it and let you know if it worked. It looks a bit complicated, so have to do a good check.

Sincerely,
Richard

Comment: You're welcome! It probably won't exactly work as is. Like I said, I couldn't test it, so it's possibly buggy. It should get you heading in the right direction though.

Comment: @RubberDuck I did a check and there are some issues. Some are minor. 
- fld in the code is sourcefolder
- Split(objFile is Split(Sourcefile
- oPDF.Utility_Merge_PDF_Files destinationFolder.Path & "\" & targetFileName should be:  oPDF.Utility_Merge_PDF_Files destinationFolder.Path & "\" & targetFileName**, Files_to_Merge**

But the comparison of the fileNames does not work. In my code it splitted the two different filenames and everything before " Anotherword 2014.pdf" or " SomeWord.pdf" was compared. As far as I can test it, it does not compare the text before the above mentioned filenames.

Comment: Okay. My code was never intended to be production code @RHBerendsen. I have said several times that I couldn't test it and it was likely to be buggy. The idea of a code review isn't to hand you working code on a platter. It's to provide insight into how you can make your code better. If you get working code from a reviewer, it should be considered a bonus, not a requirement.

Comment: @RubberDuck, thanks for the guidelines. I will check and see if I can adapt it so it will work for me. Thanks again.
Richard